# Would the temperature of a system continue to rise even if I heat it with a constant flame/burner?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

For example, suppose I heat water in a vessel that's closed with respect to surroundings, and I keep it on a burner, and continue to heat it for let's say theoretically a very long amount of time. First the obvious, It would turn into steam but what after that? Would its temperature go beyond 100 °C?

Answer (score 2):

> First the obvious, It would turn into steam but what after that? Would
>   its temperature go beyond 100 C?

By the Laws of Thermodynamics, objects exchange heat until their temperatures are equal.

So if you heat some water in a closed vessel using a Bunsen burner, the temperature in the vessel will only rise until it matches that of the flame (I'm ignoring heat losses for simplicity's sake).

So it's tempting to believe you can just 'pump' temperature from a Bunsen into some object given enough time, in reality this is simply not true.

The problem reflects the building of high temperature furnaces. A well-insulated kiln, fired with multiple propane burners inside it will approach the temperature of the burner flame but cannot rise above it.

But if the kiln  is leaking heat (poor insulation) its temperature will be significantly below that.

As mentioned in the comments, $100\text{ C}$ is not a magical temperature, it's merely the boiling point of water (at atmospheric pressure). A pressurized container would go beyond that temperature, assuming the flame temperature is $>100\text{ C}$ (and with sufficient insulation)

Comment: It would also be worth mentioning that, if the vessel is closed, the pressure will increase, and the temperature can  rise above 100 C even before all the liquid has turned to steam.  There is nothing magical about 100 C; it is just the equilibrium temperature at 1 atm pressure.  At higher pressures, the water and steam are at higher temperatures.

Comment: @ChetMiller Done, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it solved my query!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

> Would its temperature go beyond 100 C?

It would indeed. The temperature will keep rising for a while, until the amount of heat received from the flame is equal to the heat lost (by convection or radiation) to the environment. At that point the temperature stabilises.

Without further details about the system it is impossible to tell how high the temperature will go. For that you will need to know the temperature of the flame, the amount of hot gas exiting the nozzle, how much of the flame's heat actually reaches the vessel, how well the vessel conducts heat, how quickly it loses heat, etc.

In fact, under some conditions (tiny flame, large vessel, etc), the vessel may not even get up to 100 C.

Comment: Oh I get it , Thank you for answering, cheers!